# Error using solve(): Single character variable names work, but longer names give error

Tags: matlab

Does Anybody know why this code :

```
syms pi41 r C2 sigma mu C3 theta
pi41 = solve('(-2*pi41-2*r*C2+3*(sigma^2-2*mu)/sigma*C3)*theta^2','pi41')
```

has error like this :

```
Error using mupadengine/feval (line 163)
Invalid argument.

Error in solve (line 294)

sol = eng.feval('solve', eqns, vars, solveOptions);
```

But with simple characters like this code :

```
syms a b c d e f x
x = solve('(-2*x-2*a*b+3*(d^2-2*e)/d*c)*f^2','x')
```

has not ?

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Dear @StewieGriffin after writing  `evalin(symengine, 'anames()')` the `ans=` was empty and renamming `mu` does not change anything.

Comment: Again: strange suggestion: Have you tried other variable names? For instance: `aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, xx`? The reason why I ask is to find out if you get an error for all names that are more than one character, or if some of the names you have chosen are reserved.

Comment: @StewieGriffin I now try this  variable names `aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, xx` and the code works fine.

Comment: Dear @StewieGriffin , I finally find that the `theta` variable name was the problem . but why :D ???

Comment: @Roozbe: What version of matlab do you use? I am unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Dear @Daniel my MATLAB version is R2015a (8.5.0.197613)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

build two vectors, one with the equations and one with the unknowns

```
syms foo bar
eq = [  foo + bar == 5; 
      2*foo - bar == 4];
unknowns = [foo, bar];
```

then use solve

```
sol = solve(eq, unknowns)
```

or in your case

```
syms pi41 r C2 sigma mu C3 theta
eq = (-2*pi41-2*r*C2+3*(sigma^2-2*mu)/sigma*C3)*theta^2 == 0;
unknowns = [pi41];
sol = solve(eq, unknowns);
```

results in

```
sol =
- C2*r - (C3*(- 3*sigma^2 + 6*mu))/(2*sigma)
```

you also might want to specify/make sure that sigma is non zero....

...in Matlab 2015b